# Generate lognormally distributed random numbers based on another column

Tags: python, numpy

I have a column A with unique numbers being [1,2,3,4,5], and I want a column B with lognormally distributed random numbers.
I generate random numbers as follows:

```
mu, sigma = np.log(50000),1.5
uniforms = np.random.rand(num_samples) 

min_cdf = lognorm.cdf(1000, sigma, scale=np.exp(mu)) 
max_cdf = lognorm.cdf(1000000, sigma, scale=np.exp(mu))
values = lognorm.ppf(min_cdf + uniforms*(max_cdf - min_cdf), sigma, scale=np.exp(mu))
```

How to make it correlate to another column so that when the value of column A is large, the value in B is also large?